# session.persist() method confusion

Tags: java, hibernate

I read this in doc:

`persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries.`

But when I try this code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("student.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("XXX");
    student.setLastName("YYY");
    student.setCity("ZZZ");
    student.setState("PPP");
    student.setCountry("XXX");
    student.setId("NNN");
    session.persist(student);       
    session.flush();
    session.close();
```

The record is getting inserted. As you can see in the above code, I have not used any transaction. Then in that case according to the doc, the data should not be inserted in the DB right?

Transaction boundaries means any operation between `Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();` and `tran.commit();` right?

Please let me know where am I making the mistake.

Regards,

Comment: Are Transactions enabled to the Connection?

Comment: NO. Any further help on this?

Comment: @user182944 Have you got your answer ? Please share it.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `session.flush()` and `session.close()`, you'll observe that no insert statement was executed. The point of that guarantee is that the `persist` call itself won't execute any statements; it doesn't say anything about the implication on the behavior of `flush` and `close`. Indeed, `flush` flushes all persistent objects to the datastore.

Comment: if I remove the two lines you suggested, then save() also won't work. then where is the difference between the two lies?

Comment: `save` may or may not immediately execute `insert`; `persist` guarantees that it won't.

Comment: May or may not??? Under what situation does the `may` part comes? I tried a few times and in all the cases the insert was not executed :(

Comment: That's the method's contract; if you would like to find out exactly what happens---in the particular version of Hibernate you are using right now, with the particular configuration you have---the only way is to start digging through the source code. The first-level cache is the usual preferred target for all `save`s.

Answer (score 1):

This is old magic!

```
if (getTransactionIsolation()==Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE
   || getAutoCommit()==true)
```

The persist() ignores the transaction boundary!

Why? persist() does not know about support transactions or not. In second case its committed because he didnt expected to need a transaction.